# Parsing text, pseudo markup to convert to UL list for navigation php

Tags: php, parsing, explode

**I'm trying to figure out a clean way to convert this piece of text:**

1 | Level One | /url/segments/here
1 | Level One | /url/segments/here
2 | Level Two | /url/segments/here
2 | Level Two | /url/segments/here
3 | Level Three | /url/segments/here
2 | Level Two | /url/segments/here
1 | Level One | /url/segments/here
1 | Level One | /url/segments/here
1 | Level One | /url/segments/here

**Into a  structure like so:**

```
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#" title="">Level One</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="">Level One</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#" title="">Level Two</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" title="">Level Two</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#" title="">Level Three</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#" title="">Level Two</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#" title="">Level One</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="">Level One</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="">Level One</a></li>
  </ul>
```

I've attempted using explode() and messing with the arrays it creates, but i'm hitting a wall knowing when to nest the UL's when going into 2nd and 3rd level navigation.

UPDATED @ 4PM
Almost have it working, just need to figure out how to properly nest the UL within the LI, as right now it is not 100% correct as far as html markup goes.

```
<?php

$navi_text = "1 | Level One | /url/segments/here  
1 | Level One | /url/segments/here  
2 | Level Two | /url/segments/here  
2 | Level Two | /url/segments/here  
3 | Level Three | /url/segments/here  
2 | Level Two | /url/segments/here  
1 | Level One | /url/segments/here  
1 | Level One | /url/segments/here  
1 | Level One | /url/segments/here";



$each_row = explode("\n", $navi_text);


$nav_position = '1';

echo "<ul>";


foreach ($each_row as $rowKEY => $rowVAL) 
    {

        $piped_items = explode(" | ", $rowVAL);


        if($piped_items[0] == "1" && $nav_position == "1")
            {
                echo '<li><a href="">' .  $piped_items[1] . '</a></li>';
            }
        if($piped_items[0] == "2" && $nav_position == "1")
            {
                echo '<ul><li><a href="">' .  $piped_items[1] . '</a></li>';
                $nav_position = "2";
            }
        if($piped_items[0] == "2" && $nav_position == "2")
            {
                echo '<li><a href="">' .  $piped_items[1] . '</a></li>';
            }
        if($piped_items[0] == "3" && $nav_position == "2")
            {
                echo '<ul><li><a href="">' .  $piped_items[1] . '</a></li>';
                $nav_position = "3";
            }
        if($piped_items[0] == "3" && $nav_position == "3")
            {
                echo '<li><a href="">' .  $piped_items[1] . '</a></li>';
            }
        if($piped_items[0] == "2" && $nav_position == "3")
            {
                echo '</ul><li><a href="">' .  $piped_items[1] . '</a></li>';
                $nav_position = "2";
            }
        if($piped_items[0] == "1" && $nav_position == "2")
            {
                echo '</ul><li><a href="">' .  $piped_items[1] . '</a></li>';
                $nav_position = "1";
            }

    }


echo "</ul>";

?>
```

Comment: 1) From where does this text come from? File, database, ... ? 2) Show your current code and where you are stuck.

Comment: It would come out of a database, but stored in a single field/column as "text". I'm not married, to the "text" as it is, i simply am looking to provide non technical people a way to built out navigation without needing to use the html markup.

Comment: Also looking at your output I don't really see the pattern behind it, when you close the `li` tag. And when you leave it open and put another `ul` into it?

Comment: That was a quick copy paste error i made when showing what i expect the result to look like. I've fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I mean, that you close the first `li` tag right after the link, e.g. `<li><a>...</a><li>`, but the second one not, e.g. `<li><a>...<a> <ul>` <- `ul` and not a closing `li`, why?

Comment: I close that <li> after it's nested <ul><li></li><ul>

Comment: Yes it is nested, but the first one not, why is it only nested in the second one?

Comment: how you tell that "Level Two" is under which "level one" if there are multiple "level ones". is it based like which are displayed exact down they are under "level 1"

Comment: Because the first one does not have a nested level two navigation. The string will be random in terms of the nested navs for 2nd 3rd level and i need to parse that to figure out how to built the html markup. It was just an idea, hence the use of 1, 2 ,3 to tell me what level it is. Which is why i used if($piped_items[0] == "1")

Comment: Have you considered what happens if you end your nav on a level 3? You can take care of the closing tags using a stack: I just updated the code below, hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

First simply `explode()` your array by each line and go through each element with `array_map()`, where you again split each line by `|` with `preg_split()`.

After this you simply loop through each line and depending on the level you can close and open the tags as you want to:

```
<?php

    $navi_text = "1 | Level One | /url/segments/here  
1 | Level One | /url/segments/here  
2 | Level Two | /url/segments/here  
2 | Level Two | /url/segments/here  
3 | Level Three | /url/segments/here  
2 | Level Two | /url/segments/here  
1 | Level One | /url/segments/here  
1 | Level One | /url/segments/here  
1 | Level One | /url/segments/here";


    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $navi_text);
    $lines = array_map(function($v){
        return preg_split("/(\s*\|\s*)/", $v);
    }, $lines);

    $level = 0;

    foreach($lines as $k => $line) {

        if($line[0] > $level)
            echo "<ul>";
        elseif($line[0] > $level)
            echo "</ul>";

        echo "<li><a href='#' title=''>" . $line[1] . "</a>";

        if(isset($lines[($k+1)]) && $line[0] >= $lines[($k+1)][0])
            echo "</li>";
        if(isset($lines[($k+1)]) && $line[0] > $lines[($k+1)][0])
            echo "</ul></li>";
        if(!isset($lines[($k+1)]))
            echo "</li></ul>";

        $level = $line[0];

    }

?>
```

output:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='#' title=''>Level One</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' title=''>Level One</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#' title=''>Level Two</a></li>
            <li><a href='#' title=''>Level Two</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#' title=''>Level Three</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#' title=''>Level Two</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#' title=''>Level One</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' title=''>Level One</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' title=''>Level One</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I just got my version working as well. But yours definitely looks less NOOB than mine haha! **Thank You!!!**

Comment: @ipixel You're welcome. (BTW: If you want you can also post your solution and explain how you got there.)

Comment: Even though this was accepted, there's a minor flaw: if the navigation string/description ends on a 3rd level you'll need to trust the browser for the closing tags (while using a stack helps prevent that) Just updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Basic case:

```
<?php

$nav_string = "1 | Level One | /url/segments/here  
1 | Level One | /url/segments/here  
2 | Level Two | /url/segments/here  
2 | Level Two | /url/segments/here  
3 | Level Three | /url/segments/here  
2 | Level Two | /url/segments/here  
1 | Level One | /url/segments/here  
1 | Level One | /url/segments/here  
1 | Level One | /url/segments/here";

$nav_array = explode(PHP_EOL, $nav_string);
$nav_stack = array();

$first_nav = array_shift($nav_array);
$first_nav_item = explode("|", $first_nav);
$prev = 1;

echo '<ul><li><a href="#" title="">'.$first_nav_item[1]."</a>";     
$nav_stack[] = '</ul>';
$nav_stack[] = '</li>';

foreach($nav_array as $ind => $nav_item){

    $nav_items = explode("|", $nav_item);

    if($nav_items[0] == $prev){ 
        echo array_pop($nav_stack);
        $nav_stack[] = '</li>';
    } else if($nav_items[0] > $prev){       
        echo '<ul>';    
        $nav_stack[] = '</ul>';
        $nav_stack[] = '</li>';
    } else{
        echo array_pop($nav_stack);
        echo array_pop($nav_stack);
        echo '</li>';
    }

    echo '<li><a href="#" title="">'.$nav_items[1]."</a>";          
    $prev = $nav_items[0];

}

$nav_stack = array_reverse($nav_stack);
foreach($nav_stack as $stack_item){
    echo $stack_item;
}

?>
```

Will generate this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" title=""> Level One </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title=""> Level One </a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" title=""> Level Two </a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title=""> Level Two </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title=""> Level Three </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title=""> Level Two </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" title=""> Level One </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title=""> Level One </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title=""> Level One </a></li>
</ul>
```

---

Now, if your string/description of the nav menu ends on a level three, instead of trusting the browser for the closing tags: the stack will take care of them. For the following

```
$nav_string = "1 | Level One | /url/segments/here  
1 | Level One | /url/segments/here  
2 | Level Two | /url/segments/here  
2 | Level Two | /url/segments/here  
3 | Level Three | /url/segments/here";
```

The script will output this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" title=""> Level One </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title=""> Level One </a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" title=""> Level Two </a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title=""> Level Two </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title=""> Level Three </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

Comment: Still isn't the same as OP's expected output.